# MongoDB: "Unsupported projection option: pop: { $gt: 0.0 }" (debugging)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to run this query:

```
db.zips.find({"state":"GA"}, {"pop":{$gt:0}}).sort({pop:1}).limit(5)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
"errmsg" : "Unsupported projection option: pop: { $gt: 0.0 }"
```

When I run this query, it works perfectly:

```
db.zips.find({"state":"GA"}).sort({pop:1}).limit(5)
```

I'm trying to find the fields where "state" = "GA" and then where "pop" is greater than 0 and limit it to 5 results and sort them in ascending order.

When I put the `{"pop":{$gt:0}}` part as the first argument in the find function, it runs, but it ignores the fact that I only want states that equal "GA". I'm not sure how to fix this, does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Try `db.zips.find({"state":"GA", "pop":{$gt:0}}).sort({pop:1}).limit(5)`.

Comment: @Veeram that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mongodb's [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) function takes two arguments, query and projection. The query that you are firing is having two objects, second being considered as projection criteria.

Your `query` should hold all the criteria in single object.

```
db.zips.find({
               "state":"GA", 
               "pop":{$gt:0}
            })
       .sort({pop:1})
       .limit(5)
```